# Python function to writing a file

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function, it takes 3 parameters, (List1, List2, "file direction")

The function suppose to concatenate the two lists together in lines, by example

```
List1 = [Paul, Jhon]

List2 = [Architect, Ingenieer]
```

until the list is empty.

Paul - Architect

Jhon - Engineer

I think there's a problem there

```
def appending(list1, list2, file):
    filetoopen = open(file, "a")
    for i in range(len(list1)):  # posible error acá, figure it out then
        filetoopen.write("\n" + list1[i] + " - " + list2[i] % (i+1))

    filetoopen.close()  # be sure you close the file before finish.


appending(names, work, "D:\papa.txt")
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:/Users/mauro/PycharmProjects/helloworld/writefiles.py", line 29, in 
>           appending(names, work, "D:\papa.txt")
>         File "C:/Users/mauro/PycharmProjects/helloworld/writefiles.py", line 24, in appending
>           filetoopen.write("\n" + list1[i] + " - " + list2[i] % (i+1))
>       TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: Sorry, didn't mention! (names, work,"...) are currently defined. names = [
    "Robert Johnson", "Robert Planta", "Pablo Benoite", "Sergio Denis", "Enrique Durant"
]

work = [
    "Cleansing", "Singer", "Bingo", "Singer", "Athlete"
]

Comment: the elements in your list should be of type string

Comment: `with open('./test.txt', "w") as f:
        for i in list(zip(names, work)):
            f.write('-'.join(i))
            f.write('\n')`

Comment: @GOVINDDIXIT they're already string!

Comment: I have added an answer. Hope it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
list1 = ["Paul", "Jhon"]

list2 = ["Architect", "Ingenieer"]

def appending(list1, list2, file):
    filetoopen = open(file, "w+")
    for i in range(len(list1)):  # posible error acá, figure it out then
        filetoopen.write("\n {0} - {1}".format(list1[i], list2[i], (i+1)))

    filetoopen.close()  # be sure you close the file before finish.

appending(list1, list2, "a.txt")
```

**Output in a.txt**

```
 Paul - Architect
 Jhon - Ingenieer
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: I have a question, what does the 0 and 1 inside curly brackets? They indicates where the list element goes?

Comment: It is to specify the no of argument, It is just a placeholder. It also works without specifying it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you are getting this error is just that the members of a list are not a string. Once you enclose them in single or double quotation mark then there will be no error. For your clarity, look at below code-

```
def appending(list1, list2, file):
  filetoopen = open(file, 'a')
  for i in range(len(list1)):
    filetoopen.write(str(list1[i]) + " - " + str(list2[i]) + "\n")
  filetoopen.close()

List1 = ['Paul', 'Jhon']
List2 = ['Architect', 'Ingenieer']
filename = 'employee.txt'
appending(List1, List2, filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
L1 = ['Paul', 'Jhon']
L2 = ['Architect', 'Ingenieer']
filename="pytest.txt"
def list_concat(L1,L2,filename):
    cL1=0
    if len(L1) == len(L2):
        with open(filename,'w') as writefile:
            while cL1 < len(L1):
                a = L1[cL1] + " " + L2[cL1] + '\n'
                writefile.write(a)
                cL1+=1
    else:
        pass
list_concat(L1,L2,filename)
```